# Adding a desktop icon for a JavaFX native packaged app

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, inno-setup, javapackager

I have a JavaFX app that I'm doing native packaging with.  I'm packaging the app for Windows using the InnoSetup 5+ approach.  How can I set up the installer so that it creates a desktop icon for the app?

Thanks.

**Update:** I'm not sure why this has been marked as a duplicate.  I'm not using Java Web Start / JNLP (i.e. hosting my app in a web page), just native packaging for Windows to produce an .exe.

Comment: this question belongs on superuser.com ... also : you **do** know that JFX has a bundling-system with support for native packaging on its own, yes? Innosetup and the likes are completely superfluous for JavaFX projects ...

Comment: @specializt Thanks, yep I'm using JavaFX native packaging (which uses javapackager and in this case, InnoSetup)

Comment: that doesnt make any sense - there is no innosetup target in the javafx packager. You are using innosetup for your deployment, not javafxpackager (apparently).

Comment: @specializt See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html which describes javapackager and says innoSetup 5 is required for creating .exe's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to trigger desktop icon creation using `javapackager -shortcutHint=true ...`.  This works when creating .exe's and .msi's.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html.